# Incrementing concatenated list name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, concatenation

Say for example I have a number (which will change each run time) assigned to the following variable:

```
var number = 3;
```

I would like to create this many lists, whose names have a number at the end which increments every time, as follows:

```
list_0
list_1
list_2
```

I am declaring a list in the following standard format:

```
List<double> list = new List<double>();
```

I assume you would use a loop, but I am unsure as to how to correctly assign the name dynamically. Here's what I have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    List<double> ("list_" + i) = new List<double>();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at multi-dimensional arrays. Speaking of C#, more likely you need List of List of double.

Comment: Why not use a list of list?

Comment: You can't do this. How would you reference the variables created? Use a `List<List<double>>`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible the way you intend to, although you might have some luck using the [Reflection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

This is an anti-pattern though: you should know before compile time what your lists are intending to do and give them a name that describes their purpose. If you don't, you might want to not name them and simply keep their references in a list, like this:

```
List<List<Double> myLists = new List<List<double>>();

var listX = new List<double>(new[]{5.0, 2.5, 3.2});
myLists.add(listX);
```

Which will make it a lot easier for you to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is a bad practice. Most of the code written nowadays is already hard enough to read, if you try to add variables into variables names (and I'm happy the compiler forbids this) it would be truly infernal.

Instead, think of a data structure that would fit your needs; you need to have multiple variables, ordered from 0 to X. Sounds like a list to me, so you can create a List of List instead.

So if you have `int number = 3;` you can do

```
List<List<double>> lists = new List<List<double>>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    lists[i] = new List<double>();
}
```

If you want to access one of your lists after that, you easily can use the index or the LINQ `.ElementAt()`

```
List<double> listNumberTwo = lists[2];
List<double> listNumberTwo = lists.ElementAt(2);
```